# ASP.Net Identity Connect to Existing Non Identity Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, database-first

I'm working on a project in asp.net mvc. I want to authenticate users using Asp.Net Identity and Owin. I'm aware that Identity has its own tables which are created using code first approach. However, I want Identity to connect to our existing database which has existing non identity tables. Is that possible ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, asp.net identity it's [extensible](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility).

I think [this link](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) fits your needs.

Probably you need to implement your custom userstore at least and, depending on your current data structure, maybe you'll have to modify some entities.

Hope this helps!